# extract data from a different url and append the answer to a list using lxml

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I have written a script to save a list of jobs to a .html file.

The code is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies')

content = html.fromstring(page.content)

Vacancies = content.xpath('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')

f = open('scrapevacancy.html', 'w')
f.write('<br>'.join(map(str, Vacancies)))
f.close
```

However, what I also need the script to do is to access each URL for the given job, check if there is an 'Apply Now' button and append the answer to each result in the scrapevacancy.html

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies')
content = html.fromstring(page.content)
Vacancies = content.xpath('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')
f = open('scrapevacancy.html', 'w')
li = [a.attrib['href'] for a in content.xpath('//a[@class="button button__primary featuredvacancy__button"]')]
i = 0
for l in li:
    p = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/'+l)
    c = html.fromstring(p.content)
    apply = c.xpath('//a[@class="button button__primary button--dtfull"]')
    if apply:
        f.write(str(Vacancies[i]) + ' Yes <br/>')
    else:
        f.write(str(Vacancies[i]) + ' No <br/')
    i=i+1
f.close
```

Output file

> Developer (Java/Python) Yes 
> Lead Quality Assurance Engineer Yes
>   
> Senior Financial Accountant - FTC up to 12 months  Yes 
> HR
>   Officer Yes 
> HR & Training Administrator Yes 
> Front-End Web
>   Developer Yes 
> Data Centre Operative Yes

Comment: Hi Van, thank you for your response. However, the script needs to access the URL provided and check for an 'Apply now' button. If the button is there the end result would be:
Developer (Java/Python) Yes
Lead Quality Assurance Engineer No
etc.

Comment: Hi Van, again thank you so much. I am using python version 2.7.5 and when running the script I get the following error:
File "test.py", line 3, in <module> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen ImportError: No module named request

Comment: I have ensured that request was installed using pip and it is

Comment: Hi Van, I have am mended the code, however the output I get is only the first result:
Developer (Java/Python) Yes

Comment: It is a little weird, if I play around with the indents, I then get indent errors. I have the code with the exact same indents as you have provided.

Comment: File "test.py", line 14
    if apply:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: all sorted now. Thank you so much for your help in this :)